# Graph Coloring in Prolog: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, graph-coloring

I'm writing a Prolog program for a simple skill, coloring a graph. I have done everything that I had on my checklist to do: make a graph using a list of edges, make color facts, make color bindings, assign colors, check for conflicts, etc. It always returns false! I keep trying to tweak it slightly , but nothing is working:

```
color(red).
color(green).
color(blue).
color(yellow).
color(purple).
color(brown).

edge(A,A) :- [A,A].

cb(Item,Color).

graph([edge(A,A)]).

vertex(A,B) :- edge(A,B) ; edge(B,A).

colorItem([],[]).
colorItem([Item|Items], [Binding|Bindings]) :-
    colorItem(Items, Bindings),
    Binding = cb(Item, Color),
    color(Color),
    noconflict(Binding, Bindings).

colorGraph(Graph, Bindings) :- colorItem(Graph,Bindings).

noconflict(_,[]).
noconflict(Cb1,[Cb2|Cbs]) :- not(conflict(Cb1,Cb2)), noconflict(Cb1,Cbs).

conflict(cb(N1,Color), cb(N2,Color)) :- vertex(N1,N2).
```

It should look like something like this IIRC:

```
?- colorGraph([edge(ny,nj)], Bindings).
Bindings = [cb(nj, green), cb(ny, red)] ;
Bindings = [cb(nj, blue), cb(ny, red)] ;
Bindings = [cb(nj, yellow), cb(ny, red)] .
```

But I get this:

```
?- colorGraph([edge(ny,nj)], Bindings).
Bindings = [cb(edge(ny, nj), red)] 
Bindings = [cb(edge(ny, nj), green)] 
Bindings = [cb(edge(ny, nj), blue)] 
Bindings = [cb(edge(ny, nj), yellow)] 
Bindings = [cb(edge(ny, nj), purple)] 
Bindings = [cb(edge(ny, nj), brown)].
```

There's something obvious and important that I'm missing with my edges and graph. Any advice or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
colorGraph(graph, bindings) :- colorItem(graph,bindings).
```

With:

```
colorGraph(Graph, Bindings) :- colorItem(Graph, Bindings).
```

Variables start with either an underscore or an upper case letter in Prolog. Same issue apparently with some of the other predicates.

Comment: Thanks for the editing, that fixed one of the problems.

Comment: @raine Don't you have the same problem with the `noconflict/2` and the `conflict/2` predicates? Your latest edit don't show any changes to those predicates.

Comment: Whoops! I fixed them all in my actual code but not here. That solved both my "false" issues (thank you!). I edited my question to address the new problem.